# Rotate and then crop image with PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to crop my image, but when I do it shows up as the right size, but all black. I've tried at least a dozen different scripts but I can't seem to get any of them to work :(

Oh and the rotation script works fine, and all of the echos are just for testing and will be removed :D

```
<?php

$staffID        =   $_POST['u'];
$actCode        =   $_POST['a'];
$tempAvatar     =   $_POST['tempAvatar'];
$x1             =   $_POST['x'];
$y1             =   $_POST['y'];
$wH             =   $_POST['w'];
$scale          =   $_POST['scale'];
$angle          =   $_POST['angle'];
$destFolder     =   "../../../avatars/";
$imagePath      =   "tempAvatars/".$tempAvatar.".jpg";
$imagePathRot   =   "tempAvatars/".$tempAvatar."ROTATED.jpg";
$imagePathCropped=  "tempAvatars/".$tempAvatar."CROPPED.jpg";

echo 'X1: '.$x1.'<br>Y1: '.$y1.'<br>Width/Height: '.$wH.'<br>Angle: '.$angle;
if ($angle != 0) {

    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath) or notfound();
    $rotate = imagerotate($source,$angle,0);
    imagejpeg($rotate, $imagePathRot);

    $imagePath  =   $imagePathRot;
}

echo '<br>X2: '.$x2.'<br>Y2: '.$y2;

$targ_w = 300;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_w );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['w']);

imagejpeg($dst_r, $imagePathCropped, $jpeg_quality);



echo '<br><img src="'.$imagePathCropped.'">';


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$targ_h` is not defined, therefore you are copying 0 pixel "rows" from the source image. It's in the correct size because it's decided by `ImageCreateTrueColor` and of course initialized to black. The correct call according to the rest of your code should be:

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_w,$_POST['w'],$_POST['w']);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help! :D